# Creating generic method

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone please help with the following... it's driving me nuts...

```
// Three methods, virtually identical with the exception of the select field
public IEnumerable<int> GetBrandID()
{
    return myData.Select(m => m.BrandID).Distinct();
}
public IEnumerable<int> GetModelID()
{
    return myData.Select(m => m.ModelID).Distinct();
}
public IEnumerable<int> GetVehicleID()
{
    return myData.Select(m => m.VehicleID).Distinct();
}

// How to create one method which returns the type specified in the parameter??
public IEnumerable<int> GetData(??? myType)
{
    return myData.Select(m => myType).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: One pirate asked another, "Why is that ship wheel sticking out of your pants?"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably just want a `Func<Model, int>` parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetData(Func<Model, int> projection)
{
    return myData.Select(projection).Distinct();
}
```

You could then have:

```
var modelIds = GetData(m => m.ModelID);
var vehicleIds = GetData(m => m.VehicleID);
```

Is that what you're after? (That's assuming `myData` is an `IEnumerable<Model>`. If it's an `IQueryable<Model>` you may want to accept `Expression<Func<Model, int>>` instead.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance, it was clear and straight to the point and helped me immensely. Much appreciated. X22.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're exactly after. Maybe something like this?

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GetData<TModel, TResult> (this IEnumerable<TModel> enumerable, Func<TModel, TResult> projection)
{
    return enumerable.Select(projection);
}
```

And than just call like this:

```
var ints = myData.GetData<MyModel,int>(m=>m.ModelID).Distinct();
var doubles = myData.GetData<MyModel,double>(m=>m.DoubleProp).Distinct();
```

etc...

Comment: Note that if you're providing the data as well, there's no benefit in adding the method - `var ints = myData.Select(m => m.ModelID).Distinct()`...

Answer (score 0):

```
public ICollection<T> FindAllWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> selectSelector)
{
    ICollection<T> elements = EntitySet.Select(selectSelector).ToList().Distinct();

    return elements;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question, IMO... it looks like it's an answer to a different question.

Comment: It`s more generic and can change event type of int

Comment: Well no, at the moment it wouldn't even *compile*. Let's start with something that answer's the OP's actual requirements, before trying to make it more general than taht.