# Passing a function to the Contains Linq method

Tags: c#, linq

Following on from [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912406/creating-generic-method), which successfully got answered.

Why does the following code work and the more generic example fails when I include the Where() method?

```
// *** WORKS ***
private IEnumerable<int> _MySelectedData;
public void method()
{
    IEnumerable<int> distinctData = GetData(m => m.ModelID);
}
public IEnumerable<int> GetData(Func<Model, int> selectParam)
{
    return _MyData
        .Where(m => _MySelectedData.Contains(m.ManufacturerID))
        .Select(selectParam).Distinct();
}



// *** FAILS ***
private IEnumerable<int> _MySelectedManufacturers;
public void method()
{
    IEnumerable<int> distinctData = GetData(_MySelectedManufacturers, m => m.ManufacturerID, m => m.ModelID);
}
public IEnumerable<int> GetData(IEnumerable<int> _MySelectedData, Func<Model, int> whereParam, Func<Model, int> selectParam)
{
    return _MyData
        .Where(m => _MySelectedData.Contains(whereParam))
        .Select(selectParam).Distinct();
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains...

The error occurs at this line:

```
.Where(m => _MySelectedData.Contains(whereParam))
```

Hopefully someone can highlight the mistake in my ways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains` takes a *value* as the parameter, but you are passing it a *function*.  I suspect you just want to evaluate the function against the "current" item:

```
.Where(m => _MySelectedData.Contains(whereParam(m)))
```

Comment: Much appreciated, I was so close to the solution but your assistance helped solve it.